Pyinstaller и то как работает add-data
Всем привет, сейчас я пытаюсь сделать не большой установщик который переносит файл в другую папку. Я думал что если компилировать и использовать --add-data то это будет тоже самое что и файлы в одной папке, но это не так. Как это работает?

покажите команду, которой запускаете сборку. и почему вы решили, что это не "то же самое"

pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Game.exe:." installer.py.
А в коде просто указал game = "Game.exe". Само по себе оно не работает но если добавить файл в папку с установщиком то все работает
